# Match a string within column values having multiple values

Tags: r, data.table

Please help me with this
I have a data table as below

```
    dt2 <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4), variable =     c("a","b","a","c","c","d","e","b","a"))
    dt3 <- dt2[, list(variables = paste(variable, collapse = " | ")), by = ID]
    dt3[,chk:=sample(letters[1:2])]
    dt3
    ID variables chk
1:  1     a | b   b
2:  2     a | c   a
3:  3     c | d   b
4:  4 e | b | a   a
```

I want to filter records where variables contain chk. In the example above row 3 should be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an `mapply` approach. It takes the two parameters element by element in the operation:

```
dt3[mapply(grepl, x=variables, chk)]
#   ID variables chk
#1:  1     a | b   b
#2:  2     a | c   a
#3:  4 e | b | a   a
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `paste` with `grep`

```
dt3[with(dt3, grep(paste(chk, collapse='|'), variables)),]
#     ID variables chk
#1:  1     a | b   a
#2:  2     a | c   b
#3:  4 e | b | a   b
```